# Склоняются ли названия штатов?

Tags: склонение, приложение, топонимика

Есть республика Карелия, нет республики Карелии.
Есть город Москва, нет города Москвы.

**ОДНАКО:**
Почему-то есть штат Джорджия, нет штата Джорджия (27 вариантов против 1 в НКРЯ).
Есть штат Аризона, нет штата Аризона (25 вариантов против 1 в НКРЯ).

Почему так устоялось в языке? В чем логика? Или это обыкновенные ошибки?

Answer (score 3):

> В «Словаре географических названий» А. В. Суперанской (М., 2013) указано, что топонимы обычно не склоняются в сочетании со следующими географическим терминами: *болото, бухта, горы, государство, долина, залив, застава, земля* (как административно-территориальная единица), *кишлак, ключ, колодец, королевство, местечко, месторождение, мыс, область, озеро, округ, остров, перевал, плато, плоскогорье, плотина, площадь, полуостров, поселок, провинция, пролив, промысел, район* (как административно-территориальная единица), *селение, станция, урочище, хребет, **штат**.* Исключение составляют случаи, когда название выражено прилагательным: *на озере Рица*, но: на Онежском озере, в бухте Котор, но: *в Сиднейской бухте.*

Если я правильно помню, среди названий штатов и территорий США нет прилагательных, поэтому в качестве приложения все они не склоняются:
в Джорджии — в штате Джорджия, в Аризоне — в штате Аризона, в Юте — в штате Юта.

Из Нацкорпуса:
*О чем свидетельствует тот же конфликт между охранным ведомством и властями **штата Джорджии**: занятия спортом позволяют сбросить нервное напряжение, способствуют улучшению человеческих взаимоотношений* (Спорт в тюрьме (2003) // «Боевое искусство планеты», 18.10.2003).

Да, такое написание является ошибочным.

В России никогда не было штатов как территориальных единиц. Это означает, что всегда рядом со словом "штат" будет стоять иноязычное слово.
Попробуйте просклонять: Кусаие, Чиуауа, Мегхалая, Карабобо, Трухильо, Эбоньи.
Не склонять — просто и удобно.

[Как склонять географические названия?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)

Comment: Скажите, а какой смысл в обозначении падежной формы названия при наличии РОДОВОГО слова, где падеж уже обозначен? Согласование в падеже? Но вот Грамота.ру разрешает несклоняемый вариант для наших топонимов (см. В Переделкино или в Переделкине?). Более того,  даже при отсутствии родового слова (когда падеж не обозначен) допускаются оба варианта. Это российские топонимы, а что тогда говорить об иноязычных названиях, там -то зачем строгие нормы в отношении склоняемости. Вот они и не соблюдаются, чему же тут удивляться. И считать ошибкой частотный вариант мне представляется странным.

Comment: @Sharon Частотный вариант (для штатов) как раз несклоняемый. Ошибкой считается "штата Джорджи**и**". А Переделкино здесь ни при чём, это другой случай.

Comment: Тогда ответ неясен, записан нечетко. Сначала надо дать ответ: да, склонять не нужно, это будет ошибкой. А потом объяснить, в чем конкретно заключается такая ошибка, что не так, что плохо.  То есть коротко назвать причину, по которой склонять название ни в  коем случае не нужно, причем без вариантов. Почему в городе Москве, но в штате Джорджия. Информативность текста невысокая: можно прочитать много, но так и не понять его смысл. Но все, конечно, думают иначе, я не возражаю. Всем все понятно, а мне нет. Поэтому можно считать мой комментарий авторской репликой, не более того, это же не ответ.

Comment: В этой теме много факторов, которые влияют на склоняемость, и их достаточно иного (в грамматика, фонетике, лексике).  Здесь частотность варианта говорит о действии какого-то основного фактора. Вот это надо понимать и называть причину, по которой сделан выбор. Есть общие закономерности (и для Переделкино, и для штата Джорджия). Особенно нежелательно утверждать, что верен только один вариант. Для этого тоже нужна причина.

Comment: @Sharon  Дано правило, где чётко сказано, что со словом "штат" названия не склоняются. Затем дан ответ: "в Джорджии — в штате Джорджия, в Аризоне — в штате Аризона, в Юте — в штате Юта". Всё понятно.

Comment: Какое именно, там много правил и ссылок, мне бы хватило одного. Почему в список попал "штат", по какой причине? Хочется не просто выучить правило, но и знать, почему оно действует. Интересно ведь или не очень? Это правила 2013 года, может, что-то изменилось? Кстати, там написано "обычно не склоняются". Откуда однозначность?

Comment: @Sharon Ссылка одна, а правила (для тех, кто впервые столнулся с этим) полезно прочитать все – их там не так уж много. О Москве: "склоняется, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения". А также: "Варианты *в г. Москве, в городе Москве*  следует характеризовать как специфически-канцелярские (т. е. употребительные преимущественно в официально-деловой речи). Варианты *в г. Москва, в городе Москва* не соответствуют литературной норме". Мне, например, не нравится, когда в разговорной речи слышу "город" с общеизвестным названием. Про пресловутое "обычно" – согласен, я тоже ссылаюсь на него.

Answer (score 1):

**Разъяснительный ответ**

Я считаю, что ответ ясен и записан четко.
Приведено только **одно** правило:
*...топонимы обычно не склоняются в сочетании со следующими географическим терминами: <...> штат. **Исключение** составляют случаи, когда название выражено прилагательным...*

Во всех странах, в которых [*имеются штаты*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82) (Австралия, Бразилия, Венесуэла, Индия, Малайзия, Мексика, Микронезия, Нигерия, США), нет **ни одного** названия, состоящего из *одиночного* прилагательного.

**Все** эти названия являются иноязычными, нерусскими, их род и число определить иногда практически невозможно (в качестве примера я привела некоторые экзотические названия), исключений (прилагательных) на сегодня нет, поэтому логика предельно проста:
**все** названия штатов, являющиеся приложением, не склоняются (думаю, во избежание искажений и разногласий, что вполне разумно, хоть и не военное время).

В Нацкорпусе из 63 предложений со *штатом Юта* нет ни одного, где бы название склонялось.
Первый пример датирован 1930 годом — это, считаю, говорит о том, что решение "не склонять" появилось не сегодня и не вчера, а еще сто лет назад.
Если в США или другой "штатной" стране вдруг возникнет Ледовитый, или Янтарный, или Лагунный штат, то он, конечно же, "будет склоняться".

Сравним:
приложения в названиях *плато Соссусфлей, плато Кото-де-Прери, плато Финнмарксвидда* не склоняются, а *Советское, Колумбийское, Трансильванско*е — склоняются;
приложения в названиях *перевал Салават, перевал Дятлова, перевал Пхальджорён, перевал Шипка* не склоняются, а *Салаватский, Торугартский, Шипкинский* — склоняются.

Answer (score 1):

Я предложу участникам форума дискуссионную статью, где я **пытаюсь понять ЛОГИКУ.**

Просьба не миусовать)

**Диалог**

— Текст: *О чем свидетельствует тот же конфликт между охранным ведомством и **властями штата Джорджии…***

— *Склонять иноязычный топоним нельзя, это ошибка. Получается разговорный стиль.*

— *А если так:  конфликт между охранным ведомством и **властями Джорджии?***

— *Тоже разговорный. Правилен один вариант:  конфликт между охранным ведомством и **властями штата Джорджия.***

**Канцелярский язык, лицемерный  и лукавый.** Он очень любит свою канцелярскую точность, а  склонение слов эту точность нарушает.

1. **Как же выйти из положения?** Разрешаем то, что использоваться все равно не будет или используется от случая  к случаю? Вот **список**  родовых слов, в сочетании с которыми топонимы  обычно не склоняются. И **дополнение:** Исключение составляют случаи, когда название выражено прилагательным: на озере Рица, но: на Онежском озере. Но почему в этом списке *болото, кишлак, местечко, поселок* соседствуют *с государством, королевством, провинцией, областью, районом и **штатом?*** Что же между ними общего?
2. **А здесь топоним склоняется:** *в городе Москве,* в городе Санкт-Петербурге, из города Киева; в деревню Ивановку, из деревни Ольховки, в селе Шушенском, под хутором Михайловским и т.д.

Но  тут же поправка: общеупотребительно ***в Москве.*** Вариант *в городе Москве*  следует характеризовать как **специфически-канцелярский** (т. е. употребительный преимущественно в официально-деловой речи). (Да уж, в городе Москве звучит смешно или иронически.)

Получается, что склонять-то топоним **можно, но не следует.**

3. **Или вот:** подмосковный город Видное, это **прилагательное**! Его ведь нужно склонять?  Вопрос № 236353. Здравствуйте! "В городе Видное" или "в городе Видном"? "В подмосковном Видное" или "в подмосковном Видном"?
   Ответ справочной службы русского языка: Правильно: ***в Видном, в подмосковном Видном и (в канцелярской речи) в городе Видное.*** Получается, что «город» добавляется только в канцелярской речи и топоним при этом не склоняется.

**Еще вариант с прилагательным**.  Словарь указывает, что в топонимах, выраженных сочетаниями слов, части наименования должны склоняться: в городе Вышнем Волочке, однако в разговорной и профессиональной речи распространился и укоренился **несклоняемый вариант**: под городом Вышний Волочек, в поселении Долгий Мост.

4. **А что у нас со штатами Джорджия и Аризона**? Да история примерно та же. Когда мы используем это сочетание?  **Вот пример**: *Природа  штата Аризона. Штат Аризона расположен на Западе США и относится к горным штатам.* И все, сочетание «штат Аризона»  больше  практически не используется, только Аризона:  на юге Аризоны, население  Аризоны.
5. А если мы будем **описывать российский город**?  *История города Тверь. Тверь – это город в центре России, расположенный на реке Волга . В Твери много парков и скверов.* В названии — вступительный канцелярский вариант без склонения, а  потом сочетание больше не применяется.
6. И еще **про прилагательное.** Пусть у нас будет  штат **Новая Аризона**, как тогда будем составлять текст? Да по тому же образцу. Природа  штата  Новая Аризона. Для Новой Аризоны характерна горная местность. А если шатат **Аризоновый**? Нет. склонять не будем.
7. Получается, что запрещение/разрешение в некоторых случаях **формально** и мало на что влияет? Но это **не совсем так**, просто надо учитывать **стилевую характеристику всего сочетания**. Склоняемость в общем случае  придает тексту разговорно-художественный характер, а несклоняемость — официально-деловой. Поэтому нужно **правильно использовать родовое слово** (приложение).
8. Так в чем же разница между **русскими и иноязычными топонимами**?
   ***Власти города Москвы*** — это правильно?  Скорее нет, достаточно сказать: ***власти Москвы***, и это будет деловой стиль. А для иноязычного топонима нужно добавить приложение: ***власти штата Джорджия.***

Comment: *Власти Джорджии, власти Аризоны, власти Юты...* — так можно (никто и не говорил, что *так* нельзя, и это совсем не разговорный вариант). *Правозащитники подали в суд на **власти Джорджии** из-за нового избирательного закона (RTVI). **Власти Джорджии** подтвердили победу Джо Байдена* (Euronews). ***Власти Джорджии** сообщили, что...* (Российская газета). ***Власти Джорджии** по-прежнему заявляют...* (Коммерсантъ).

Comment: Статья дискуссионная, все мнения мои собственные и они относятся только к теме  вопроса, а не к ответу.  Мне просто хотелось объяснить, почему у МЕНЯ  так много вопросов по ЛОГИКЕ, в то время как остальным участникам  все ясно.  Даже сам список мне кажется странным; в нем не только "иноязычный" штат, но и государство и т.д. Эту логику я тоже не понимаю (не дано).  Разрешенное согласование в общелитературной речи не применяется, а только в особых стилях. А в этих стилях есть запрет на склонение. В чем здесь логика? Склонять можно, но не нужно – это логика?

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Какое такое государство?

Comment: В этом списке есть "государство".  А это приложение вообще-то используется, например "в государстве Финляндия"? Кто так скажет? Или как нужно говорить, официальное название использовать, А в официальном стиле склонение и так не рекомендуется. Тогда зачем этот список? Нелогичный он какой-то.

Comment: Ну не знаю... ***Государство Австралия** является крупнейшим производителем овечьей шерсти и, соответственно, лидирующим экспортёром среди ведущих стран* (География, 7 класс). *Конкурентам стоит волноваться, потому что **государство Люксембург** с 1956 по 1993 год побеждало на Евровидении пять раз* (Postimees). ***Государство Израиль**: вопросы идентичности* (Московский журнал международного права).

Comment: Здесь имеется в виду государство, а не материк или еще что. Полезная информация. Кстати, И.п., склонения нет.